# Creating labels from reports

Tags: database, ms-access, report

I am using this coding -

=Trim([Customer Order ref] & [Description] & [Product Code] & [Quantity] & [Order No] & [Delivery Date])

It works and gives me all the information which I need however i can't manage to get spaces inbetween the details given...any idea how I can get spaces?

Thanks in advance Dominique Brennan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include them:

```
=Trim([Customer Order ref] & " " & [Description] ...
```